# ActiveMQ Artemis server produces lots of AMQ224016 error in logs after migration to Jakarta API client

Tags: java, kotlin, jms, activemq-artemis

I encountered a problem using Artemis ActiveMQ server - AMQ224016 error. Starting with version 2.20.0, but then with upgrade to 2.32.0 along with clients (diferrent combinations, clients 2.20 or 2.32 connecting to server 2.32).
The problem occured after migration from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.x (which changed the jakarta.jms-api from 2.0.3 to 3.1.0 along with jakarta imports).

Here is example stacktrace from artemis.log file:

```
2024-03-18 12:08:46,069 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224016: Caught exception
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQIllegalStateException: AMQ229027: Could not find reference on consumer ID=0, messageId = 25612055904 queue = example.queue
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl.individualAcknowledge(ServerConsumerImpl.java:1013) ~[artemis-server-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.individualAcknowledge(ServerSessionImpl.java:1314) ~[artemis-server-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.slowPacketHandler(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:618) ~[artemis-server-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.onMessagePacket(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:319) ~[artemis-server-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.Actor.doTask(Actor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.32.0.jar:2.32.0]
```

This stacktrace shows up for every handled message which generates over 500MB of logs every day in my case, and before that there was only like ~100KB of server logs each day.

There wasn't a problem when using client in older service with Java 8 and artemis-jms-client:2.19.1 (becase 2.20.0+ clients are meant for Java 11+) and in other service that used Java 17, Spring Boot 2.7 and artemis-jms-client:2.20.0.
For tests I created example application running on Java 17, newest 2.32.0 client and the only change is Spring Boot version from 2.7.18 to 3.0.x/3.1.x/3.2.x/ along with jakarta imports (no changes in listener implementation) - on older Spring Boot there is no problem on server side.

Furthermore I tried different combinations of Artemis instances - newly created instance with default configuration and other clusterd instance (2 primary, 2 secondary), default and configured queue, with every combination the effect is the same - on older jms-api it is ok and on newer it's not.

I see that Artemis supports JMS 3.1.0 api (JakartaEE 10) from version 2.23.0.

Are there any options on what I can do and what can be missing/incompatible?

**MRE**

Requirements to reproduce the problem:

- instance of artemis server 2.32.0 with default configuration (client connecting to tcp host on 61616)
- client application with listener using Spring Boot 3.x, Jakarta JMS 3.x api

Full example repository (with sender): https://github.com/g4iner/artemis-tester/ and gist: https://gist.github.com/g4iner/ad2ad8d09a56aa538809833739866d54

My listener implementation (handles ExampleMessage from "example.queue"):

ExampleMqListener.kt

```
@Component
class ExampleMqListener : MqListener<ExampleMessage> {
    override fun handleMessage(message: ExampleMessage): Boolean {
        return runBlocking {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleMqListener::class.java).info("Incoming ExampleMessage: $message")
            true
        }
    }
}

data class ExampleMessage(val data: String) : MqMessage

class MqListenerImpl<T : MqMessage>(private val messageConverter: MessageConverter, private val handler: MqListener<T>) : MessageListener {
    override fun onMessage(jmsMessage: Message) {
        val message = messageConverter.fromMessage(jmsMessage) as? T ?: error("Unexpected message type")
        runCatching {
            handler.handleMessage(message)
        }.getOrElse {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(MqListenerImpl::class.java).error("Unable to handle message", it)
        }
        jmsMessage.acknowledge()
    }
}

interface MqListener<T> {
    fun handleMessage(message: T): Boolean
}
```

MqListenerConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
class MqListenerConfig(
    override val listenerContainerFactory: DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory,
    override val jmsListenerEndpointRegistry: JmsListenerEndpointRegistry,
    override val messageConverter: MessageConverter,
    private val mqListeners: List<MqListener<out MqMessage>>,
) : JmsListenerConfig {
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent::class)
    fun startListeners() {
        mqListeners.forEach {
            listenToQueue(it)
        }
    }

    private fun <T : MqMessage> listenToQueue(handler: MqListener<T>) {
        handler.messageType().let {
            listen(
                listenerConfig = ListenerConfig(it.simpleName, it.simpleName, "example.queue", "1-2"),
                handler = handler,
                messageClass = it
            )
        }
    }

    private fun <T : MqMessage> MqListener<T>.messageType(): Class<T> = (javaClass.genericInterfaces[0] as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = ["type"])
interface MqMessage : Serializable {
    val type: String
        get() = javaClass.simpleName
}

class ListenerConfig(
    val messageType: String,
    val id: String,
    val destination: String,
    val concurrency: String
)

interface JmsListenerConfig {
    val listenerContainerFactory: DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory
    val jmsListenerEndpointRegistry: JmsListenerEndpointRegistry
    val messageConverter: MessageConverter
}

fun <T : MqMessage> JmsListenerConfig.listen(
    listenerConfig: ListenerConfig,
    handler: MqListener<T>,
    messageClass: Class<T>
) = SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint().apply {
    id = listenerConfig.id
    destination = listenerConfig.destination
    concurrency = listenerConfig.concurrency
    selector = "_type = '${messageClass.canonicalName}'"
    messageListener = MqListenerImpl(messageConverter, handler)
}.let {
    jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(it, listenerContainerFactory, true)
}
```

MqConnectionConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mq")
@EnableJms
class MqConnectionConfig {
    var front: MqConfig = MqConfig()

    @Bean
    fun backConnectionFactory(): SingleConnectionFactory =
        SingleConnectionFactory(createFactory(front)).apply {
            setReconnectOnException(true)
        }

    private fun createFactory(config: MqConfig) =
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory(config.url).apply {
            user = config.user
            password = config.password
        }

    @Bean
    fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(): DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory().apply {
        setConnectionFactory(backConnectionFactory())
        setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter())
        setSessionAcknowledgeMode(ActiveMQJMSConstants.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jmsListenerEndpointRegistry(): JmsListenerEndpointRegistry = JmsListenerEndpointRegistry()

    @Bean
    fun jacksonJmsMessageConverter() = MappingJackson2MessageConverter().apply {
        setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT)
        setTypeIdPropertyName("_type")
        setObjectMapper(jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
            configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        })
    }
}

class MqConfig {
    var url: String = "tcp://localhost:61616"
    var user: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
}
```

dependencies used in build.gradle.kts

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
```

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce this error? The move from `javax` to `jakarta` should be transparent to the broker as the wire protocol didn't change. The only change is the class names on the client. Also, is there a specific reason why you're not using the [latest version](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (i.e. 2.32.0 at this point).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't provide example earlier. Now I updated Artemis to latest version (2.32.0) but there is no change, the problem still exists in logs.

I prepared a gist with example implementation: https://gist.github.com/g4iner/ad2ad8d09a56aa538809833739866d54
And after changing the Spring Boot version to 2.7.18 and jakarta imports to javax the problem is resolved, what do you think about that?

Comment: I need a way to reproduce the issue or I can't really tell what's going on. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least clear steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes I added my implementation in example gist. Now main classes are added also to thread, please take a look

Comment: Is Spring absolutely required to reproduce this problem? If so, that indicates a problem within Spring. If not, then Spring should be removed from the reproducer.

Comment: Also, it's not clear how these files should be structured. Do they all simply go in the same directory? A properly structure Git repo would be much better than a handful of copied & pasted files.

Comment: Yes the repo will be better, here it is with same files: https://github.com/g4iner/artemis-tester/
I created the example with Spring but I'm not sure it is needed, just for the ease of implementation,

Comment: There are no instructions on how to actually run the application. If Spring isn't needed to reproduce the problem then it should **definitely** be removed. Spring is quite a thick integration layer and although it may make implementation easier it makes testing the broker much harder. The reproducer should be _minimal_, after all.

Comment: I added missing instructions on how to run the application to the current repository, just the command that spring boot provide, pretty straightforward. Try if it's understandable. If I will have time to refactor the application I will try to make it easier, but now it doesn't involve much code

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I was able to reproduce what you're seeing, but it's hard to tell what's going on with Spring in the mix. The problem is that while your application code is simple Spring is doing a lot in the background. Also, is there a specific reason you're using `INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE`? Using `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` resolves the issue so I don't think this has anything to do with switching from `javax` to `jakarta`. It's something to do with Spring JMS 3.x and individual acks.

Comment: @JustinBertram you are right, I debugged the ACK fragment and the problem is the additional use of "jmsMessage.acknowledge()" in the message listener implementation - the method is called twice. The client automatically calls this method and I see that there is no need to use it explicitily. So with INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE the second call of "individualAcknowledge" method  causes that problem on the server side, because the message was already acked. The use of INDIVIDUAL_ACK is probably not needed in this scenario, that was ported from another implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by usage of `jmsMessage.acknowledge()` in the application's `MessageListener` implementation. Spring automatically acknowledges the message so there is no need to manually invoke this method in the code.

Additionally, in the above implementation the use of `INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE` is unnecessary and `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` can be used.